# Status: Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, profile, provisioning

Status
Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run
destination to have Xcode register it. [Try Again)
No profiles for •com.likeminds.app' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development
provisioning profiles matching 'com.likeminds.app'.

I changed the "Bundle Identifier" to something less generic (e.g. adding some random numbers at the end)